# After upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 18.10, polybar is now crashing with SIGSEV

Tags: upgrade, 18.10

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04, to Ubuntu 18.10, but now polybar is crashing and outputting this:

```
[~]::polybar example
fish: “polybar example” terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)
```

Here's my polybar config: https://pastebin.com/raw/tFBxh069

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got the package from a non-official PPA and the package is also for 18.10, contact the package maintainer since the package likely needs to be recompiled for 18.10.

If you have built the polybar yourself you likely have to completely recompile *and* reinstall it. For this follow the [install instructions](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/wiki/Compiling#building) and make sure you use a clean build directory and not the one you used to compile it on 18.04.

---

Btw. support for 18.10 ends this month (July 2019) so better upgrade to 19.04 ;)

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot haha, I completely forget I compiled polybar and that I didn't install it from the repos. Thanks for your help man